# How can I change the prompt [Please Select] from a combo box in zAppDev

Tags: zappdev

I have some combo boxes and I want to change the [Please Select] prompt to something else. How can I do this? Is there a way to change it globally to all combo boxes?

https://www.screencast.com/t/6QznC709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can change it at 'Localization' tab of the Form Editor.

[image]

2. No there isn't.